# How to test mapping for a Grails 3 domain class

Tags: testing, grails, spock

Given a domain class like:

```
class Person {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        name column: 'TheName'
    }
}
```

The `name` attribute for the Person is actually mapped to the `TheName` column in an SQL table.

So how can I test, using Spock, to make sure that mapping is present in the domain class? How do I get access to the mapping when I create a new Person object as such:

```
new Person(name: 'Anderson')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after?

```
GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping( Person ).getPropertyConfig( 'name' ).columns
```

Will get you something like:

```
[column[name:TheName, index:null, unique:false, length:-1, precision:-1, scale:-1]]
```